# ¿Cómo puedo crear un tabbar con subcategorías?

Tags: android, flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de crear este tabbar anidado con categorías, subcategorías y tiendas. No puedo resolver el filtro de las subcategorías y tiendas. Estoy usando MySQL.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: con.categories.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(155),
            child: AppBar(
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                   _textFieldSearch(context),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              bottom: TabBar(
                onTap: (int index) {
                  con.roberto.value = con.categories[index].id!;
                  print('Cat Seleccionada:${con.roberto.value} ');
                },
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: List<Widget>.generate(con.categories.length, (index) {
                  return Tab(
                    height: 90,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 5,
                      ),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 70,
                                    height: 55,
                                    child: FadeInImage(
                                      image: con.categories[index].image !=
                                          null
                                          ? NetworkImage(
                                          con.categories[index].image!)
                                          : AssetImage(
                                          'assets/img/no-image.png')
                                      as ImageProvider,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      fadeInDuration:
                                      Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                                      placeholder: AssetImage(
                                          'assets/img/no-image.png'),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  con.categories[index].name ?? '',
                                  style: Helper.getTheme(context)
                                      .headline6
                                      ?.copyWith(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
              children: List<Widget>.generate(con.categories.length, (index) {
                return HomeTopTabs(context);
              })
          ),
        ));
  }



HomeTopTabs(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: con.categories.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(55),
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              indicatorWeight: 2.0,
              indicatorColor: Colors.red,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'SubCat 1',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'SubCat 2',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'SubCat 3',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'SubCat 4',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: con.categories.map((category) {
            return FutureBuilder(
                future: con.getCommerces(con.roberto.value ?? '',con.roberto2.value ?? '',
                    con.productName.value ?? ''),

                builder: (context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<Commerce>> snapshot) {
                  //        print('camaro:${this.camaro}');
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (snapshot.data!.length > 0) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                            return _cardProduct(
                                context, snapshot.data![index]);
                          });
                    } else {
                      return NoDataWidget(
                          text: 'Categorías sin Productos');
                    }
                  } else {
                    return NoDataTextWidget(
                      text: '',
                    );
                  }
                });
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
 }
```